# What are the differences between "element" and "item" regarding a list

Tags: meaning, word-choice

Does it make a difference if I use *element* instead of *item* in the context of a list (list-member)?

Comment: Are we talking HTML here?

Comment: No. I would try to remain consistent, though. If I refer to *items* in an array, then I wouldn't suddenly switch to *elements*. The words are synonymous, *unless you are using some specific programming terminology as Andrew hints at*. In that case there may be distinctions made in the programming language you're using.

Comment: As a programmer, I have always used the word _element_ when referring to arrays and _item_ when referring to lists. That's probably just my preference though.

Comment: It is not HTML. It is an array/list past as an argument to a function.

Comment: Ok, so I will use `item` without switching.

Comment: Actually, if it's an array, I'd use *element*.